# How to set class variable through __init__ in Python?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to change setting from command line while starting a scrapy crawler (Python 3.7). Therefore I am adding a **init** method, but I could not figure out how to change the class varible "delay" from within the **init** method.

Example minimal:

```
class testSpider(CrawlSpider):

    custom_settings = {
        'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 10,  # default value
    }

    """ get arguments passed over CLI
        scrapyd usage: -d arg1=val1
        scrapy  usage: -a arg1=val1
    """
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(testSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.delay = kwargs.get('delay')

        if self.delay:
            testSpider.custom_settings['DOWNLOAD_DELAY'] = self.delay
            print('init:', testSpider.custom_settings['DOWNLOAD_DELAY'])

    print(custom_settings['DOWNLOAD_DELAY'])
```

This will not change the setting unfortunatelly:

```
scrapy crawl test -a delay=5
10
init: 5
```

How can the class variable be changed?

Comment: It *is* being changed... `init: 5` ... why do you think it isn't?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to change? ``delay`` is an *instance* variable in your code; there is no *class* variable ``delay`` in it. Note that the ``print`` is part of the ``class`` block and thus runs at *class* definition time – that is long before ``__init__`` runs – and it checks ``testSpider .custom_settings['DOWNLOAD_DELAY']`` which is a separate "variable" from the ``delay``.

Comment: Note that your supplied output shows `10` printed *before* the init method is run, whereas you place the print statement at class level outside the init function.  You almost certainly *don't want* to be running code outside of class methods: it gets messy pretty quickly.  (precisely because the placement is irrelevant: the print is executed when the class is defined, not when the init is run)

Comment: I am trying to change custom_settings['DOWNLOAD_DELAY'] which is set within each spider as illustrated. This is I believe the standard way to set the delay within scrapy within a spider. In certain cases I want to change this setting right from CLI, which is the reason I am trying to solve this with __init__. Maybe there is another way, but I could not find another way to access the CLI parameter from within the spider.

Comment: In that case your code is probably already doing what you want. You just have to run the ``print(custom_settings['DOWNLOAD_DELAY'])`` *after* parsing the command line.

Comment: @merlin again *your code is already doing this*. Why do you think it isn't?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga scrapy reads `custom_settings` from spider only one time a long before spider's `init` method called.
Yes. Technically it will update `custom_settings` variable hovewer by this moment scrapy application already initialised with "old" `custom_settings`. As result it will not work as @merlin expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am trying to change setting from command line while starting a
> scrapy crawler (Python 3.7). Therefore I am adding a init method...
>
> ...
>  `scrapy crawl test -a delay=5`

1. According to [scrapy docs. (Settings/Command line options section)](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/2.5/topics/settings.html#command-line-options)
   it is requred to use `-s` parameter to update setting
   `scrapy crawl test -s DOWNLOAD_DELAY=5`
2. It is not possible to update settings during runtime in spider code from `init` or other methods (details in related discussion on github [Update spider settings during runtime #4196](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/4196)

Comment: Thank you, that worked. For others looking into this and using scrapyd, the right syntax is: -d setting=DOWNLOAD_DELAY=5